# Sencha Touch 2: How to handle custom css files while production build?

Tags: html, css, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am working on a mobile website developed using sencha touch 2. I had used sencha cmd v3 to generate the production build. When i tested the production build, I found that my custom css files are included in the folder structure but the custom styles are not applied on the UI elements.

Please see, I am not using SASS/COMPASS in this application. Any ideas on where things went wrong or I missed out anything? Do I have to treat custom css files differently and do something special while creating the production build? Do I need to include references of these custom css files in app.json while creating the production build? Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You need to include css file in the html. And if you are doing so, may be the url is incorrect

Comment: Hi Amrit. I have included the custom css files in index.html and they were working fine in development version. But when I created the production build, the custom style classes are not being applied on the UI elements and the custom css files became ineffective. I have not added the custom css files references to app.json, Can it be the issue?

Comment: may be, you never know. Or you can try adding css styles in app.css, that will surely work if your style rules are correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just give the reference in `app.json` file. Add it after `app.css` file

```
/**
         * List of all CSS assets in the right inclusion order.
         * Each item is an object with the following format:
         *      {
         *          "path": "path/to/item.css" // Relative path to this app.json file
         *          "update": "delta"          // (Optional)
         *                                     // - If not specified, this file will only be loaded once, and
         *                                     //  -cached inside localStorage until this value is changed to either one below
         *                                     //  - "delta" to enable over-the-air delta update for this file
         *                                     //  - "full" means full update will be made when this file changes
         *
         *      }
         */
```